# Sidekiq UI not loading assets (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I am using Sidekiq in a Rails app and am having troubles getting the UI working.

When I go to `http :// servername/sidekiq` the sinatra app loads, but looks like this: http://cl.ly/NHBT

The error in the log is:

`Started GET "/sidekiq/javascripts/application.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-01 11:32:48 -0700`

NoMethodError (undefined method `empty?' for #<Rack::File:0x007faf004527c8>):
  bullet (4.3.0) lib/bullet/rack.rb:31:in`empty?'
  bullet (4.3.0) lib/bullet/rack.rb:12:in `call'
  warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in`block in call'
  warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in`call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in`call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original problem ended up being solved with a newer release of sidekiq

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue as well. 
Appearently, the [Bullet gem](http://librelist.com/browser//sidekiq/2013/1/11/assets-not-loading-in-development-mode-as-of-2-6-x/#720c07c4a83fd48213452ff84e1dc26d) is causing this.

For now I've just decided to disable Bullet, because there's no [way on the documentation to skip Bullet for mounted apps](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet) or similar configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm still having the issue, but came up with the following workaround:

Add to `config/initializers/sidekiq_bullet_workaround.rb` (or similiar):

```
module Rack
  class File
    def empty?
      false
    end
  end
end
```